# Does Truffle Test consume gas?

Tags: truffle, ganache-cli

When I run the $truffle test command in the terminal does it consume any gas from my local blockchain(say Ganache)?

Comment: You can try and test it yourself. Run a test for a payable function and you will know.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your test. if your test contains transaction ( which is used by using `.send()` ), Yes you are using gas and ether from your local client. and in order to test and see the Ether inside the account you can do this :

```
let balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);
console.log(balance);
```

Make sure you have extracted your account before, with this code:

```
accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
```

Also don't forget to do this in an async mode

Answer (score 0):

Yes as mentioned by @Masoud answer. You can however avoid it by either manually passing for each transaction the option `{ gasPrice: 0 }`. Or you can set the defaults for a contract to use a gas price of 0:

```
MyContract.defaults({
    gasPrice: 0,
})
```

Then your tests consume in fact no gas.